# Adding a `updatedDate` column in TypeORM without using the Typescript decorator `@UpdateDateColumn`

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, typescript, typeorm

I am using Javascript for a project and cannot work out how to include a `updatedDate` column without using the Typescript `@UpdateDateColumn` decorator.

In Typescript:

```js
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedDate: Date // works perfectly but unfortunately I am not using TS in this project
```

In Javascript:

```js
    createdDate: {
      type: 'timestamp', // works fine
    },
    updatedDate: {
      type: 'timestamp', // throws error + everything else I have tried has also thrown an error.
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    updatedDate: {
      type: 'time', // works!!!
    },
```